# Black out the screen during a Windows 10 restart up to a certain point in time

Tags: windows, cmd, restart

Is there a way to temporarily disable the display during a Windows 10 PC restart? 
Background: we have a software, which is set to start up automatically after a PC restart. Upon startup (after Windows has booted) this software starts in a console window and then opens a WPF screen, which is displayed fullscreen and always resides in front of everything else. I would like to black out the screen ideally as early as possible during the Windows startup up to the point in time when our software WPF window is set and ready on the screen. This way the console window (as well as the desktop showing for a short period of time) would be hidden from the user. 
In an ideal world I would hide the fact that Windows is running on the PC from the user, but I assume this is not possible over a restart...

Is this possible with the help of registry settings/command line tools/batch file commands or similar?